# Why does this infinite series equal one? $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{2k}{k} \frac{1}{4^k(k+1)}=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients, taylor-expansion

Why does

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{2k}{k} \frac{1}{4^k(k+1)}=1$$

Is there an intuitive method by which to derive this equality?

Comment: One explanation which would be quite intuitive (if one could find it) would be to interpret each term as the _probability_ of some event. Then adding the terms up to get 1 would make simply mean that there's a certainty of _something_ happening. (But I'll admit, I don't see such an interpretation off the top of my head.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Given the appereance of $\binom{2k}k$ and $2^{2k}$, I would urge you to think about picking certain subsets of $[2k]$! (I haven't thought about it, though)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff:  I was thinking something like: flip coins with certain odds until you've got as many heads up as heads down. Either that or something relating to these being the catalan numbers $\times 4^{-k}.$

Comment: Creative telescoping might be surprising sometimes :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your series is a telescoping one, since:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}\binom{2k+2}{k+1}-\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}&=&\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}\binom{2k}{k}\left(\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}-4\right)\\&=&-\frac{1}{2(k+1)4^{k}}\binom{2k}{k},\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{4^k(k+1)}=2\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}-\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}\binom{2k+2}{k+1}\right)=\frac{2}{4}\binom{2}{1}=1.$$
No need of generating functions or integrals.

Comment: Very nice. Haven't seen this proof before.

Comment: Typo, I suppose. Shouldn't that be $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ ?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a counting proof. Suppose I play the following game: I flip a coin once; assume w/o loss of generality that it's heads. I then continue flipping that coin until exactly as many tails have come up as heads. What is the probability $P(k)$  that a total of $k$ heads and $k$ tails will have been seen?

First, note that a given sequence of $2k$ coin flips has a probability of $2^{-2k}$ of occuring. However, not all sequences of coin flips are allowed: only those where the number of heads is always at least as much as the number of tails. (So $HTHHTT$ is fine but not $HTTTHH$). Hence it may not be obvious how to count this.

Luckily this counting problem is well-known, and the number of allowed outcomes of length $2k$ is the $k$th *Catalan number* $C_k=\dbinom{2k}{k}\dfrac{1}{k+1}.$ (See the Wikipedia article for details.) Consequently the probability of $k$ heads and $k$ tails occuring is $P_k=C_k\,2^{-2k}$.

With that in mind, what is the probability of *any* outcome occuring? It must of course be a certainty, so we conclude that $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty P_k 
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{2k}{k} \frac{2^{-2k}}{k+1}=1$$
which is exactly the identity desired.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thanks! I debated whether or not to include a derivation of $C_n$ as well but decided it wasn't crucial for explaining the intuition.

Comment: You still need to show that the probability of never seeing the same  number of heads and tails is 0.

Comment: For a rigorous explanation, sure. But the poster asked for intuition, and that point seems sufficiently technical as to not be necessary. @JimmyK4542

Comment: Since you've invoked a theorem for the Catalan number formula, you could invoke a theorem about random walks in place of "it must of course be a certainty" :-) The notion of the coin-tosses continuing forever is precisely the notion of no outcome occurring.

Comment: This is great! =D

Answer (score 8):

The generating function of $x_n=\dfrac{1}{n+1}\displaystyle\binom{2n}n$ is $$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$