# Random walks with finite chance of escape

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, summation, random-walk

In a recent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879181/137524) I gave a combinatorial interpretation for the sum $\sum_{n=1} \binom{2n}{n}\frac{4^{-n}}{n+1}=1$: namely, that it corresponded to the probability of all outcomes adding to $1$. A few commentators objected that I was taking for granted that such a game had no chance of lasting forever. That was a valid point, though one I felt comfortable leaving out of an intuitive explanation...

However, that left me wondering about the following question. **What are some good examples of terminating random walks with finite 'escape' probability?** (That is, a random what such that the stopping probability does not go to one as the number of steps goes to infinity.) As a secondary question: **What are some notable summations implied by such walks?**

Comment: ${{}}$ random what?

Comment: Makes sense---heck, I wouldn't be surprised if it was actually a probability of 1 in that case. (I chiefly had 1D models in mind, since it seems much more likely to find tractable summations in that case.) @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: I am not an expert in the field, but I would bet that for a random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ the probability of never hitting again the line $x=y=z$ after the start in the origin is positive.

Comment: I was inspired by the non-ergodicity of the 3d-Brownian motion and the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\gamma$ has two connected components, while $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is a curve, is connected, so I am expecting that there are plenty of random paths avoiding a special $\gamma$ (the line $x=y=z$) in $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Agreed. I'd even expect there to be many many more random walks that escape than return in that case.

Comment: @Semiclassical: we may study the distribution of $D=(x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2$ for the $n$-th step of the random walk, and see if the expected value stay bounded or diverges.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The probability to never hit this line is zero in 3D because "nice" 2D random walks are recurrent.

Comment: @Did: Right. Not sure how one comes up with a summation identity in that case...(maybe some kind of tabulation of all the 'ways' it can escape? not seeing an easy route.)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry but we are not here to exchange arguments (in the sense of *feelings*, really): the statement in my last comment is well known and can easily be made fully rigorous, if one desires. Note that already in 1D, the expected value of the distance to the starting point goes to infinity.

Comment: ((Comment by @JackD'Aurizio now deleted.))

Comment: @Did: I was considering the squared distance from the line $x=y=z$, indeed. Am I wrong by saying that such a random variable has a $\chi^2$ distribution with a larger and larger expected value?

Comment: Mmh, I just realized that the distribution of the squared distance is a $\chi^2$ with only two degrees of freedom. Ok, but this should work for real: the $\chi^2$ random variable with $3$ degrees of freedom has a bounded pdf in a a neighourhood of zero, hence for a random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^4$ the probability of never hitting again the line $x=y=z=w$ after the start is positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example is a biased $\pm1$ random walk with $p\gt1/2$ probability of a $+1$ step, starting from $1$, stopped when it first hits $0$. Probability of "escaping" to infinity is $2-1/p$.

"Hence", for every $p$ in $(0,1)$, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n+1}{2n\choose n}p^n(1-p)^n=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\frac1p&\text{if}&p\gt\frac12\\\frac1{1-p}&\text{if}&p\leqslant\frac12\end{array}\right.$$
(Which is the extension to every $p$ of the summation you recalled for $p=1/2$ at the beginning of your post.)

Comment: That was quick! Can you answer the summation part of the question as well?

Comment: Yes. Can you? $ $

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I suppose I should approach it in the spirit of a Catalan problem.

Comment: Perfect. I'd still like to see more exotic examples, but this quite captures the kind of answers I'm looking for. (An obvious generalization of this would be to allow multiple step lengths, but that feels too engineered to be very interesting.)