# Find the sum, if exists $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2(n+1)}
$$

By comparison test this series converges. Any nice way to work the sum?

---

I see that this can be written as:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}(n+1)}
$$

Comment: It can also be rewritten as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\frac{1}{n+1}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}$, where $(2n)!!=2n(2n-2)(2n-4)...$, and similarly $(2n-1)!!=(2n-1)(2n-3)...$

Comment: Exactly ! the original problem was like that : $\dfrac{1}{2\cdot 4} + \dfrac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4 \cdot 6} + \dfrac{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5}{2\cdot 4 \cdot 6\cdot 8}+ \cdots$   I have worked the $n$th term for convergence test and hoping to find the sum :)

Comment: Note that this is the same as evaluating the generating function of the Catalan numbers at $x=1/4$.

Comment: I'd just stick to Shubham's method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this infinite series equal one?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879022/why-does-this-infinite-series-equal-one)

Comment: As proved in the other question, your series is a (non-trivial) telescopic sum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the following expansion:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n}x^n$$
Integrate both the sides under the limit $0$ to $x$ i.e
$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{1-4x}-1\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2x}\left(\sqrt{1-4x}-1\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n}\frac{x^{n}}{n+1}$$
Substitute $x=1/4$ to get:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{2n \choose n}}{n+1}\frac{1}{4^n}=2 \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{2n \choose n}}{n+1}\frac{1}{4^n}=1$$

Comment: thats brilliant xD thank you :)